# Finding Positions in C String

Tags: c, string, search

If I have a C string that contains *'s and I want to find the position of the 3 star in this string. What is the best/ more efficient way to do it other than going through a loop and checking char by char?

Thanks

Comment: There is not other way checking char by char, cause the string isn't sorted.

Comment: A way is to use information theory, if the probability to find an asterisk depends on other characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do the searching with [`strchr`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strchr/). Since you want the third instance of the character, you'll still execute that in a loop.

Whether this will actually be more efficient than writing a loop on your own may be open to some question, but it probably won't be any slower, and the intent will be more clear to anybody reading the code.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto: It will search character by character, but may not be the same. Just for example, on x86 some compilers implement it using `rep scasb`, which (depending on the exact processor) is often 20-30% faster than a normal loop. It is unavoidable that it has the same algorithmic complexity though (O(N) either way).

Answer (score 1):

C strings are actually array of characters , so if you want to find the position of any character then yoou will have to traverse the whole array and return the position of particular `char`. But the indexing of array starts at position `0`.

finding one character postion

```
int str_chr_pos(const char *s,char c)
{
 for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
   if(c == s[i])
     return i;  // found at position i
 return -1;   //-1 means not found and check the returned value in the calling environment
}
```